# Factorization in the Sense of Primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Are there types prime factorizations in the sense of primes other than the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (and its generalization to euclidean/principle rings), primary decomposition and Dedekind domains?

Comment: The prime cycles of a graph, it leads to the $\zeta$ function of graphs. Whenever there are some unique factorization, there is a $\zeta$ function, so this is a good starting point : [List of zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, but then it becomes essential to distinguish between irreducible and primes, as they are not always the same.

For a non-unit number to be irreducible, it's enough that it's not the product of two other non-unit numbers. But for it to be prime, it must be divide at least one factor of any product that it's a divisor of.

For example, in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$, we see that 2, 3, $2 - \sqrt{10}$ and $2 + \sqrt{10}$ are all irreducible but not prime, since $2 \times 3 = (-1)(2 - \sqrt{10})(2 + \sqrt{10}) = 6$, yet in this ring $2 \nmid (2 \pm \sqrt{10})$, $3 \nmid (2 \pm \sqrt{10})$.

However, 7 is prime in this domain. You can find nonzero multiples of 7 with more than one factorization, but in every case you will find 7 irreducible in those factorizations.

Not quite sure if that's what you're looking for. Maybe this: a domain "smaller" than $\mathbb Z$, which consists solely of positive integers of the form $4k + 1$. If we start with $\mathbb Z^+$, we remove integers of the forms $4k$, $4k + 2$ and $4k + 3$ so that we are left with 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, etc.

Clearly 1089 is composite in this domain. Its prime factorization is $3^2 \times 11^2$. Oops, that's wrong, since neither 3 nor 11 is of the form $4k + 1$. Instead it's factorizations are $9 \times 121 = 33^2$. Therefore 9, 33 and 121 are all irreducible but not prime.

For a number to be prime and irreducible in this domain, it has to be a prime of the form $4k + 1$ in $\mathbb Z$. So 5 is prime and irreducible in this domain, sometimes called $\mathcal S$. We see, for example, that 2205 has more than one distinct factorization in this domain, but the blame for that goes to 441, not 5.

And here is one where things get really trippy: the finite $\mathbb Z_{10}$, consisting entirely of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Addition and multiplication are adjusted to keep arithmetic within $\mathbb Z_{10}$, e.g., $5 + 5 = 0$. Then 5 is prime but not irreducible, as $5 = 5^2 = 5^3 = 5^4 = \ldots$

Comment: also $3^2.7^2 = (3.7).(3.7)$ so the factorization is not unique

Comment: @user1952009 Yeah, that's the very first example of non-unique factorization in $\mathcal S$.

Comment: @user1952009 Are you the person who has down voted this post ? ( I was waiting to up vote this answer) ... I must admit I do not fully understand the complete flavours of factorisations that can occur in Rings & Fields ... I would love to know ... maybe you can give fill this gap in my knowledge ? & give us a comprehensive answer ? (or good ref would do)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit no, I didn't downvote. I think the approach primes vs irreducible is a good starting point. But I didn't upvote because I understand the question as "what is the generalization of primes, beside numbers fields and algebraic varieties". Personnally I can only give examples, and it won't be very different to this [list of zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions)

Comment: Also I'm not able to speak about [schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)) which is, I think, made for generalizing the cases where primes and zeta functions are interesting. And $4 \mathbb{Z}+1$ is a multiplicative monoid, which is interesting because it is defined additively, as the prime numbers (and Dedekind rings), but it lacks unique factorization.

Comment: @user1952009 Maybe we should up vote this post ?(It does add something positive) ... There are PID's & UFD's & allsorts & that I would love to know about this stuff ... you're comments give me some leads to follow & I am grateful for this ... Sorry if I offended you by accusing you as the down voter ... $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @Donald Sometimes answers get downvoted not so much because they're wrong but because someone doesn't like the question (which is currently nominated to be closed as "unclear what you're asking," which is understandable). It's also possible someone thinks I've misunderstood the question, and that would also be a good reason to downvote. After you reach a certain threshold, you shouldn't worry about the occasional downvote. Still, thanks for your upvote.